# Lookup Category, Subcategory based on column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, lookup-column

I've used the [Asset manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-templates-in-microsoft-365-62f0e4cf-d55d-4f89-906f-4a34e036ded1) template to for a list of the companies machines. I would like to edit the Modell column, to be a lookup from another list.

This list contains all models, but also a subcategory and a category (see example below). The user should only have to fill in the Modell column, e.g. R34. The column Subcategory (Desktop) and Category (Computer) should be filled automatically.

How can I "lookup" the values for Subcategory and Category based on Modell?

```
+----------+-------------+--------+
| Category | Subcategory | Modell |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| Computer | Laptop      | Aspire |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|          |             | X10    |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|          |             | X20    |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|          | Desktop     | T20    |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|          |             | T540   |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|          |             | R34    |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| Printer  | MFP         | C434   |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|          |             | B463   |
+----------+-------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration for the lookup field, you can have SharePoint bring over additional column values. In this case, the Category and Subcategory.

[image: Models list]

[image: Lookup column additional settings]

[image: List view]